# URL Rewrite PHP and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, uri

I need to change the site URL from this:

```
www.thesite.com/thepage.php?lang=it
```

to this:

```
www.thesite.com/it/thepage.php
```

But I need this to work even if the folder `it` doesn't exist.

And of course I also need the PHP file to read back `www.thesite.com/it/thepage.php` to this `www.thesite.com/thepage.php?lang=it`.

I've looked at many posts on StackOverflow and the documentation but can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)?

Comment: I did try but couldn't figure it out, otherwise I wouldn't ask... And for Quentin, I did look at other answers but still couldn't figure it out... I may be stupid but... :D

Comment: Also show the code of your .htaccess

Comment: Is your web server Apache? Or maybe something else?

Comment: I THINK is Apache as the first line you gave me worked "RewriteRule ^([^//]+)$ thepage.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]". Otherwise where do I find what server I have?

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^//]+)$ thepage.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

To make `thepage.php` also a dynamic try this one

```
www.thesite.com/it/thepage.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/([^//]+)$ $2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That sounds good, but "the page" could be any page, like index.php, this.php, other.php... etc.. How would that be?

Comment: Can't see why but it's not working: [http://www.aquapol.mc/index.php?lang=it](http://www.aquapol.mc/index.php?lang=it)

Comment: its working perfect i have tried it on my localhost your url should be `http://www.aquapol.mc/it/index.php`

Comment: Ok, did you try clicking the link above? Does it work on your browser? Mine doesn't work, I see that address and doesn't go in /it/index.php
My .htaccess has only this two lines:

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/([^//]+)$ $2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: You can download/see my .htaccess here: [HTACCESS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5r2yfdhdg7te2vj/.htaccess)

Comment: Then there must be something to do with your server configuration

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z]+)/(.+) $2?lang=$1
```

Comment: Can't see why but it's not working: [http://www.aquapol.mc/index.php?lang=it](http://www.aquapol.mc/index.php?lang=it) ... see yourself